# Mongodb schema.find() is taking too long against 1010 records

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

```
const apprenticeshipstandards = await Apprenticeshipstandard.find();
```

it returns the data in more than 4 mins. any better way of querying find() to mongodb docs? it was working fine but suddenly started taking more than 4 mins fetch all docs

This is my schema actually fetching the data from external api and replicating into my database. now trying to fetch it from my own database and its taking too long to fetch.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const ApprenticeshipstandardsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    templateType : {
        type : String
    },
    larsCode : {
        type : String,
    },
    referenceNumber : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    title : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    status : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    url : {
        type : String
    },
    versionNumber : {
        type : String
    },
    change : {
        type : String
    },
    changedDate : { 
        type : String 
    },
    earliestStartDate : { 
        type : String 
    },
    latestStartDate : { 
        type : String 
    },
    latestEndDate : { 
        type : String 
    },
    overviewOfRole : {
        type : String
    },
    level : {
        type : Number
    },
    typicalDuration : {
        type : Number
    },
    maxFunding : {
        type : Number
    },
    route : {
        type : String
    },
    keywords : {
        type : Array
    },
    jobRoles : {
        type : Array
    },
    entryRequirements : {
        type : String
    },
    assessmentPlanUrl : {
        type : String
    },
    ssa1 : {
        type : String
    },
    ssa2 : {
        type : String
    },
    version : {
        type : String
    },
    standardInformation : {
        type : String
    },
    occupationalSummary : {
        type : String
    },
    knowledges : {
        type : Array
    },
    behaviours : {
        type : Array
    },
    skills : {
        type : Array
    },
    options : {
        type : Array
    },
    optionsUnstructuredTemplate : {
        type : Array
    },
    proposalApproved : {
        type : String
    },
    standardApproved : {
        type : String
    },
    epaApprovalDate : {
        type : String
    },
    fundingApprovalDate : {
        type : String
    },
    eQAProvider : {
        type : Object
    },
    approvedForDelivery : {
        type : String
    },
    integratedApprenticeship : {
        type : Boolean
    },
    integratedDegree : {
        type : String
    },
    tbReference : {
        type : String
    },
    tbMainContact : {
        type : String
    },
    involvedEmployers : {
        type : String
    },
    regulated : {
        type : Boolean
    },
    regulatedBody : {
        type : String
    },
    coreAndOptions : {
        type : Boolean
    },
    typicalJobTitles : {
        type : Object
    },
    greenJobTitles : {
        type : Object
    },
    englishAndMathsQualifications : {
        type : String
    },
    reviewDetails : {
        type : String
    },
    pathway : {
        type : Object
    },
    cluster : {
        type : Object
    },
    createdDate : { 
        type : String 
    },
    lastUpdated : { 
        type : String 
    },
    occupationalStandardUrl : {
        type : String
    },
    standardPageUrl : {
        type : String
    },
    qualifications : {
        type : Array
    },
    professionalRecognition : {
        type : Array
    },
    duties : {
        type : Array
    },
    regulationDetail : {
        type : Array
    },
    optionsUnstructuredKsbMapping : {
        type : Array
    },
    careerStarter : {
        type : Boolean
    },
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Apprenticeshipstandards', ApprenticeshipstandardsSchema);
```

This is the explain plan

```
{"explainVersion":"1","queryPlanner":{"namespace":"RubitekDB.apprenticeshipstandards","indexFilterSet":false,"parsedQuery":{},"maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached":false,"maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached":false,"maxScansToExplodeReached":false,"winningPlan":{"stage":"COLLSCAN","direction":"forward"},"rejectedPlans":[]},"executionStats":{"executionSuccess":true,"nReturned":1011,"executionTimeMillis":13,"totalKeysExamined":0,"totalDocsExamined":1011,"executionStages":{"stage":"COLLSCAN","nReturned":1011,"executionTimeMillisEstimate":12,"works":1013,"advanced":1011,"needTime":1,"needYield":0,"saveState":1,"restoreState":1,"isEOF":1,"direction":"forward","docsExamined":1011},"allPlansExecution":[]},"command":{"find":"apprenticeshipstandards","filter":{},"skip":0,"limit":0,"maxTimeMS":60000,"$db":"RubitekDB"},"serverInfo":{"host":"ac-hwcjvc4-shard-00-02.rwi1fym.mongodb.net","port":27017,"version":"5.0.13","gitVersion":"cfb7690563a3144d3d1175b3a20c2ec81b662a8f"},"serverParameters":{"internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes":104857600,"internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes":104857600,"internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes":16793600,"internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes":104857600,"internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes":33554432,"internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS":0,"internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes":104857600,"internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes":104857600},"ok":1,"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":"7158726415230173191"},"signature":{"hash":"g2I1o5BLMSdftjXrP0sffIDyIM8=","keyId":{"low":11,"high":1655126098,"unsigned":false}}},"operationTime":{"$timestamp":"7158726415230173191"}}
```

Comment: We're going to need more information to assist. Please upload the verbose explain output (`.explain("executionStats")`) for the query and also describe the environment where the database is running (what version, is it a replica set, are the servers hosting it in the cloud, etc)

Comment: I am using the Mongo DB Atlas cluster.

Comment: I have just executed simple find query over almost 1k records. and this is what it has returned. status: 200 OK  Time: 4m 42.54 s  Size:151.38kb

My cluster is in MongoDB Atlas.